# Django: how to check if Q object is empty?

Tags: python, django

I am chaining nodes to a `Q` object the following way:

```
q = Q()
for filter in filters:
    if filter_applies(filter):
        q.add(Q(some_criteria), Q.OR)
```

What means the `q` object might or might not have been chained a node. Later on I am trying to apply the `q` object in a filter, but only if this is not *empty*:

```
if q.not_empty():
    some_query_set.filter(q)
```

How can I check that `q` is not the same than it was when defined?

Comment: Does it matter? Surely an empty Q is just a no-op?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It **does** matter because inside the `if q.not_empty()` block I am performing other (somewhat costly) operations that don't make sense/are irrelevant/unnecessary if `q` is empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to check if `q` is empty or not you can check its length:

```
>>> q = Q()
>>> len(q)
0
```

Alternatively, you can first prepare a `dict` of filters to be applied:

```
lookups = {}
for filter in filters:
    if filter_applies(filter):
        lookups[filter] = some_criteria
```

Then you can check if its not empty apply filters using `Q` object:

```
import operator

if lookups:
    qs = qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, [Q(f) for f in lookups.items()]))
```

Comment: Of course I can do that. But I'm asking for a way to check if a `Q` object is "empty".

Comment: @dabadaba Updated my answer, you can check `len(q)` if returns 0 its empty.

Answer (score 5):

An empty Q object is falsy (`bool(Q())` evaluates to `False`), so I think you should just check it that way:

```
if q:
    some_query_set.filter(q)
```

You shouldn't be checking if the length == 0, since that expression costs more.